# Referencing other excel sheets in formula

Tags: excel-formula

So not able to use vba just yet but need the syntax to reference another sheet when using excel formulas I have tried:

=if((=‘test1’!A3)> 0, ‘test1’A1, B6*F6))

Or something along those lines just a example

Any help would be appreciated, I’m sure it’s something simple I’m messing up. It’s excel 2007 btw.

Thank you!

Comment: There's a couple issues with the formula you posted. Are you just trying to do this? `=if(‘test1’!A3 > 0, ‘test1’!A1, B6*F6))`

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you! Also how do I flag your comment as correct, there is only a option for me to report it.

Comment: @JoshEller Please re-post as an answer.  OP - Once its posted as an answer, please upvote and checkmark to mark as accepted.

Comment: Will also need to change the quotes from `\`` to `'`